# On a certain property of the different of an extension of an algebraic number field of a prime relative degree

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field.
Let $A$ be the ring of integers in $K$.
Let $L$ be an extension of $K$ of a prime degree $p$.
Let $B$ be the ring of integers in $L$.
Let $\mathfrak{D}_{L/K}$ be the different of $L/K$.
Suppose every prime factor of $\mathfrak{D}_{L/K}$ does not divide $p$.
Let $\alpha \in A$.
Suppose $X^p - \alpha$ does not have a root in $K$.
Let $\Gamma$ be an element of B such that $\Gamma^p = \alpha$.

My question: Is the following proposition true? If yes, how would you prove this?

**Proposition**
$\Gamma$ is divisible by every prime factor of $\mathfrak{D}_{L/K}$.
In particular, $\Gamma$ is not a unit.

**Motivation**
This came from the following question.

[Is there a purely imaginary unit in the cyclotomic number field of an odd prime degree?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175006/is-there-a-purely-imaginary-unit-in-the-cyclotomic-number-field-of-an-odd-prime)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $B$ contains the order $A[\Gamma] = A[X]/(X^p - \alpha),$ and
so the different of $B$ (i.e. $\mathfrak D_{L/K}$) contains the different of $A[\Gamma]$, which equals $p\Gamma^{p-1}$.   Thus every prime factor of 
$\mathfrak D_{L/K}$ divides $p \Gamma^{p-1}$.  By assumption these are all prime
to $p$, and so in fact every prime factor of $\mathfrak D_{L/K}$ divides
$\Gamma^{p-1}$, and so divides $\Gamma$.  Thus the first part of your proposition
is true.

The second part is *not* true, because $\mathfrak D_{L/K}$ could be the unit ideal.  E.g. take $p = 2$, $K = \mathbb Q[\sqrt{-5}]$, and $L = \mathbb Q[\sqrt{-5},i]$,
with $\alpha = -1$ and $\Gamma = i$.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot it could be the unit ideal.